# Why do I have this ERROR: syntax error at or near "Array" LINE 2: VALUES Array?

Tags: php, postgresql, sql-insert

I was following the examples given here on this thread

[Why is insert not working and not outputting any error on postresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62639647/why-is-insert-not-working-and-not-outputting-any-error-on-postresql)

While I am trying to insert multiple values using this option inside the data base; I encountered this error "ERROR: syntax error at or near "Array" LINE 2: VALUES Array.." Could any assist please? Below is the code:

```
       …….

       "INSERT INTO people( mom, non, ooo)
      VALUES 
    ($1,   $2,  $3), 
   ($4,   $5,  $6),
   ($7,   $8,  $9),
   ($10, $11, $12)

  ON CONFLICT (mom) DO NOTHING";

   $rcon = pg_query_params($connection, $ins, 
   Array(
   [ $mom ,$non,  $kooo],
   [ $mom 1,$non1,  $kooo1],
   [ $mom 2,$non2,  $kooo2],
   [ $mom 3,$non3,  $kooo3]
       )
   );

   if(!$rcon){
   echo pg_last_error($connection);
       }else{
            echo "Record added to database</br>"; //success confirmation
      }


  This gives this error;  ERROR: bind message supplies 4 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're providing an array of arrays for your parameter binding. Try this instead:

```php
    $rcon = pg_query_params($connection, $ins, 
        [
            $mom,  $non,   $kooo,
            $mom1, $non1,  $kooo1,
            $mom2, $non2,  $kooo2,
            $mom3, $non3,  $kooo3,
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what arrays have to do with your question. Presumably, you want to insert multiple rows. That would be:

```
INSERT INTO people( mom, non, ooo)
VALUES 
    ($1,   $2,  $3), 
    ($4,   $5,  $6),
    ($7,   $8,  $9),
    ($10, $11, $12)
ON CONFLICT (mom) DO NOTHING
```

Comment: I did that and it showed this: ERROR: bind message supplies 4 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 12

Comment: @Vvictory  To answer your problem here, the Array you are passing is an Array of Arrays.  Get rid of the square brackets (`[` and `]`) inside of your `Array`, and it should work.  But even if that does work for you, you are doing this wrong.

Comment: @MikeOrganek could you suggest a better way please?.. because it keeps showing the bind message supplies error.

Comment: @Vvictory Please edit your question with your code updates and the error message.